# How is argv handled internally?

Tags: c

Here is some code from K&R that describes command-line arguments

```
int getline(char *s, int lim)
{
    int i = 0;

    while(i < lim - 1 && (*s = getchar()) != EOF && *s++ != '\n')
       i++;

    if(*s == '\n')
      *s++ = '\n', i++;

    *s = '\0';
    return i;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   

     char line[MAXLINE];
     long lineno = 0;
     int c, except = 0, number = 0, found = 0;

     while(--argc > 0 && (*++argv)[0] == '-')
        while(c = *++argv[0])
          switch(c) {
             case 'x':
                  except = 1;
                  break;
             case 'n':
                  number = 1;
                  break;
             default:
                  printf("find: illegal option %c\n", c);
                  argc = 0;
                  found = -1;
                  break;
          }

     if(argc != 1)
         printf("Usage: find -x -n pattern\n");
     else
         while(getline(line, MAXLINE) > 0) {
             lineno++;
             if((strstr(line, *argv) != NULL) != except) {
                   if(number)
                      printf("%ld:", lineno);
                   printf("%s", line);
                   found++;
             }
         }

     printf("Found: %d", found);
     return found;
}
```

There is another question on here involving this, but there are a few things still not clear to me.

First of all, are the array of pointers in `*argv[]` handled internally as pointers to string constants, pointers to multiple arrays, each containing a string, or pointers to different spots in a single array, an array that holds all of the strings? **I really only need a single sentence answer for this.**

Comment: It's an array of pointers. The pointers point to individual strings (read: null-terminated arrays of `char`). It is not specified whether these strings are stored in one big character array or not. Why do you need to know?

Comment: Note that the argument processing shown is not particularly robust.  If you write programs that parse options, especially long-name options like `--output`, then use `getopt()` or `getopt_long()` functions rather than trying an ad hoc loop as shown.

Comment: n.m. All of this is leading to another question, but I didn't want people to ignore this very important first question and focus on the next question. I'm about to post the other one in a few minutes. I was trying to mess with some syntax in my compiler involving a pointer array to string constants to better understand the code posted above, but I noticed the syntax for working with ptr arrays to string constants and ptr arrays to arrays containing strings are not the same. I needed clarification first.

Comment: Ex, for a ptr array to string constants: `(*++name)[0]` seems illegal, but this syntax is legal for the code above, (*++argv)[0]. This implies to me that they're not the same.

Comment: Also, `*++name[0])` gives me the next character in a string constant, in the code above, it would increments to the next command line argument: `*++argv[0])`

Comment: We're going to need to see your code to know what you're up to and why the two are different.  It also matters whether the 'arrays' are function parameters or file scope variables or function scope (non-parameter) variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The strings are not string constants, but you can consider them as pointers to multiple arrays each containing a string or as pointers to different spots in a single array that holds all the strings; the typical implementation on Unix is such that you can't tell the difference between the two, but other implementations could lay out the data differently because the standard only requires an 'as if' implementation that behaves as described by the standard (the relevant section of which is §5.1.2.2.1 Program startup) — and all that's a single sentence to meet the requirements of the question.

Answer (score 3):

A single sentence: it depends *entirely* on the implementation.

Expanding: provided the implementation follows the rules as laid out in the standard, it's free to arrange the actual character arrays however it sees fit.

The *pointers* in `argv` have to be consecutive (and `argv[argc]` must be `NULL`) but the character arrays that they point to can be all over the place, with the proviso that *each* argument has consecutive characters with a null terminator.

So it, could be:

```
argc == 2
+---------+---------+---------+
| argv[0] | argv[1] | argv[2] | --+
+---------+---------+---------+   |
  |            |                  V
  |            +-----------+     NULL
  |                        |
  V                        V
+---+---+---+---+---+----+---+---+----+
| s | l | e | e | p | \0 | 6 | 0 | \0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+----+---+---+----+
```

or, equally valid:

```
argc == 2
+---------+---------+---------+
| argv[0] | argv[1] | argv[2] | ------------+
+---------+---------+---------+             |
  |            |                            V
  |            +------------------------+  NULL
  |                                     |
  V                                     V
+---+---+---+---+---+----+ (any old   +---+---+----+
| s | l | e | e | p | \0 |  rubbish   | 6 | 0 | \0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+----+     here)  +---+---+----+
```

Comment: Also, the content of the strings must be writable (but the standard does not state either way whether the pointers are writable or not)

Answer (score 0):

Implementation specific.

> for a ptr array to string constants: (*++name)[0] seems illegal, but this syntax is legal for the code above, (*++argv)[0]. This implies to me that they're not the same.

Yes, both might not be the same. Consider following example

```
void modify(char *arg[]);
int main()
{
    static char *name[] = { "Illegal month", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar" };
    
    // printf("%s\n", *++name); This would result in error Lvalue required.
    // Since we can't change the address of array. 

    modify(name);
    return 0;
}    
void modify(char *arg[])
{
  printf("%c \n", (++arg)[0]); // this is legal since arg is pointer. 
}
```

> Also, *++name[0]) gives me the next character in a string constant, in the code above, it would increments to the next command line argument: *++argv[0])

*++argv[0] should too give the next character.

I don't have enough reputation to comment so had to post it as an answer.